# json get field name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to push the Field Names into the option value and the result into the text of a select.  It should look like this:

```
<select id="ddl_fields">
    <option value="RoleId">e407d28a</option>
    <option value="RoleName">Sales</option>
</select>
```

This is the json object returned from the database:

```
"[{"RoleId":"e407d28a","RoleName":"Sales"}]"
```

This is the code and it pulls back a valid result:

```
function getFields(){
        var the_id = $(".hid_ID").val();
        var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ id: the_id });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "bc_Admin.aspx/getFields",
            data: jsonText,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.d != "0") {
                    var obj = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                     //what needs to change???
                    $.each(obj, function (index, value) {
                        $('#ddl_fields')
                        .append($("<option value=" + value.id_Role + ">" + value.RoleName + "</option>"));
                    });
                }
            } //end success
        });
    }
```

Similar to this questions but need a JQuery solution.
[How to get/list all field names of a JSON data with ExtJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370828/how-to-get-list-all-field-names-of-a-json-data-with-extjs)

Thanks!

Comment: what is the output? Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: `value.id_Role` or `value.RoleId`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `data.d` is in the format you posted `obj` is an array and you want to iterate the object in the array and not the array itself.

```
$.each(obj[0], function (index, value) {
    $('#ddl_fields')
    .append($("<option value=" + index + ">" + value + "</option>"));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to iterate through the keys of the object, and use `hasOwnProperty` to make sure its a key of the object and not of its prototype.

```
var key, keys = [];

for (key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
    keys.push(key)
}
```

Comment: That because you're testing an array and not an object.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to loop through the object and use hasOwnProperty().

```
for (var i in inputData) {
  if (inputData.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
  console.log(i + " , " + inputData[i]);
}}
```

This example will just log to console key: value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
$.each(obj, function (index, value) {
```

to

```
$.each(obj[0], function (index, value) {
```

---

The problem is that you return an array in your json

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand, but here's what I would do to get what you want (I made also your code simplier):

```
function getFields(the_id){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "bc_Admin.aspx/getFields",
        data: { id : the_id },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                console.log(i + ": " + data[i]);
            }
        },
        error : function(s , i , error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Louis XIV, I thought you died in 1715 but no matter, your javascript is bang up-to-date.

Comment: I'm back from hell just for jQuery :)